# using the Access requests and invitations link in site settings gives EDIT instead of others

Tags: permissions, office-365

I have noticed something that even tho it is not a bug, it bugs me to no end.

It happens frequently that the feature "access request automatic email" is used and the person responsible gets the email with accept or decline.

If you use the automatic link in the email or you go to the Access requests and invitations link in site settings you are given the option of EDIT and READ.

I have seen in many situation that when people are explained what is the difference between edit and contribute, everybody prefers contribute but in the above situation you should decline and add the person manually. Is there a workaround to this? like setting the Access requests and invitations link in site settings as Contribute and READ?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround can be to make a copy of the edit permission level and reduce the default Edit permission level to contribute level. Main difference between the two is the "Manage List" permission which is required for adding the tasks to a timeline when using a project site template.